# I am trying to install numpy to my vscode project

Tags: python, numpy

I am very new to python and VScode I have experience with Xcode but this has really stumped me I want to install numb to my project but I can't figure out what to put into my terminal for it to work.

I am using python version 4.1 this is what I put in `py -m pip pip install numpy` but this doesn't seem to work any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you mean by 'this doesn't seem to work".  What exactly happens when you run that command?

Comment: please, follow this guideline https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: “*I am using python version 4.1*” Somehow, I doubt this, since no such version of Python exists. Do you mind clarifying your statement? See [ask]

Answer (score -1):

[try:-] pip install --upgrade pip

[then:-] pip install numpy

in your vs code terminal